# Simplifying the Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I use this Makefile to build a small C++ application:

```
BIN_CPP=Main
CPP=g++
INCLUDES_APR=/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1
LIB_SRC = $(wildcard My*.cpp)
LIB_OBJ = $(LIB_SRC:.cpp=.o)
RM=rm

all: Main

MyClass.o: MyClass.cpp
    $(CPP) -I$(INCLUDES_APR) -c $< -o $@

MyModel.o: MyModel.cpp
    $(CPP) -I$(INCLUDES_APR) -c $< -o $@

libMyLibrary.so: $(LIB_OBJ)
    $(CPP) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^

Main.o: Main.cpp
    $(CPP) -o $@ -c $^ -I$(INCLUDES_APR)

Main: libMyLibrary.so Main.o
    $(CPP) $^ -o $@  -L/usr/local/apr/lib -L. -lapr-1 -lMyLibrary

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -f *.o *.so $(BIN_CPP)
```

When I remove then first two targets and extend the libMyLibrary.so one, it fails:

```
# MyClass.o: MyClass.cpp
#   $(CPP) -I$(INCLUDES_APR) -c $< -o $@

# MyModel.o: MyModel.cpp
#   $(CPP) -I$(INCLUDES_APR) -c $< -o $@

libMyLibrary.so: $(LIB_OBJ)
    $(CPP) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^ -I$(INCLUDES_APR)
```

and the error message is this:

```
g++    -c -o MyClass.o MyClass.cpp
In file included from MyClass.cpp:1:
MyClass.hpp:3:10: fatal error: apr_general.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <apr_general.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: MyClass.o] Error 1
```

The `-I$(INCLUDES_APR)` is missing from the automake output. What is wrong with this build file?

Comment: The default recipe for those is `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c` which isn't aware of `INCLUDES_APR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the explicit rules, you are relying on GNU make's built-in rules to compile your files, which is good.  But GNU make's built-in rules can't possibly know about your local variable `INCLUDES_APR`, so when it compiles the source files that variable is not used.

You should add the `-I` flag to the standard variable `CPPFLAGS` (the "CPP" here stands for "C preprocessor", not "C++"), which is what make uses to compile in its built-in rules.

Example:

```
BIN_CPP=Main
CPP=g++
INCLUDES_APR=/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1
CPPFLAGS=-I$(INCLUDES_APR)
LIB_SRC = $(wildcard My*.cpp)
LIB_OBJ = $(LIB_SRC:.cpp=.o)
RM=rm

all: Main

libMyLibrary.so: $(LIB_OBJ)
        $(CPP) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^

Main: Main.o libMyLibrary.so
        $(CPP) $< -o $@  -L/usr/local/apr/lib -L. -lapr-1 -lMyLibrary

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) -f *.o *.so $(BIN_CPP)
```

Possible `make` output

```
g++  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
g++  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -c -o MyClass.o MyClass.cpp
g++  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -c -o MyModel.o MyModel.cpp
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libMyLibrary.so MyClass.o MyModel.o
g++ Main.o -o Main  -L/usr/local/apr/lib -L. -lapr-1 -lMyLibrary
```

Comment: Mind if I append my edited Makefile to your answer? I was about to write the same thing as you. :) I'll put it in. If you don't like it you can always remove it.

Comment: What you said (" ... you are relying on GNU make's built-in rules to compile your files ...) was completely new for me. I learned something new.

Comment: @KérdezösködőIndián You can disable the built-in rules by writing [an empty rule for `.SUFFIXES:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html)

Comment: Probably you want to reverse the order of the library includes: `-lMyLibrary -lapr-1`.  Order of linking _does_ matter and you want the "using" libraries to appear before the "used" libraries (so if `MyLibrary` makes use of `apr-1` then `MyLibrary` should be first on the link line).

Comment: Note that GNU make has two different kinds of implicit rules: suffix rules and pattern rules.  Adding `.SUFFIXES:` will delete all the default suffix rules, but not the default pattern rules.